Is the convolution between two CDF always well defined?
Given the integral convolution:
$$(F_X * G_X)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x F_X(t)G_X(x-t)dt $$
and also that the CDF of random variables are bounded between the interval $(0,1)$ and the flipping of one of them in the product inside the integral make me think that:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}F_X(t)G_X(x-t)=\lim_{t\to-\infty}F_X(t)G_X(x-t)=0 $$
Is always this integral well define, or there are cases where is not?

Since the integrand is necessarily non-negative, it's always well-defined as an $\mathbb{R}\cup{\infty}$-valued function.  Do you mean something more than that?

@BrianMoehring Nop, good enough for me

In Probability Theory one defines $(F*G)(x)=\int F(x-y)dG(y)$. This is more useful than convolving $F$ and $G$ as functions. This is itself a CDF and corresponds to the sum of two independent r.v's with CDF's $F$ and $G$.

@geetha290krm Do you mean $F*g=\int F(x-y)dG(y)$ instead?
